# What essential oils can I use that my cat would also like?

Tags: cats, safety

Does anyone know any essential oil that cats like to smell? It seems, that my cat likes nothing. Maybe the smell of oils is too strong. I have tried fir-tree, pine, mint, melissa, eucalyptus, orange, lavender.

Comment: Catnip, obviously... Most others are likely to be uninteresting to a carnivore, and if applied enough for us nose-blind humans to notice may be stronger than a cat woud prefer.  What are you trying to accomp,ish?

Comment: @keshlam just want to find the smell, that will be pleasant both to humans (me) and a cat. I like aroma oils, but can not use them, because the cat does not like:)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Essential oils are NOT recommended for use with cats without professional guidance. The National Association for Holistic Aromatherapy states:

> Essential oil use for felines (cats) is very limited due to a cat’s
>   sensitive metabolic system and their internal organs: the liver and
>   kidneys do not breakdown certain substances due to lack of enzymes.
>
> Some hydrosols-hydrolats (the aromatic-water by product that remains
>   after the steam distillation process of plant material: flowers,
>   leaves, twigs and bark for essential oil use) can be a gentle and safe
>   alternative for animals, and even for cats if used in minute amounts:
>   Always use under the guidance of a professional aromatherapist.

[Animal Aromatherapy and Essential Oil Safety By Kelly Holland Azzaro, RA, CCAP, CBFP, LMT](https://www.naha.org/assets/uploads/Animal_Aromatherapy_Safety_NAHA.pdf)