# My cat keeps vomiting and isn’t acting like herself, should I be worried?

Tags: cats, veterinarian

My wee 6 month old kitten vomited up a small piece of plastic a few days ago. I have no idea where it came from as we are super cautious with cat proofing as she likes to eat random things from the floor. She was fine afterwards so I didn’t think too much of it. It’s been days and over the last 24 hours she’s been acting more tired than usual, also been clinging to me like crazy and eating a lot less. She’s still eating a little and drinking more water than usual but what she’s eating is a a lot less. She just vomited again clear liquid twice within the span of 10 minutes and I’m wondering if I should be contacting the vet about this? She ate a little bit right after and went to sleep. I’m quite worried!

Comment: Please contact your vet right this minute.

Answer (score 4):

What you describe are possibly symptoms of your cat being poisoned or being infected with a gastrointestinal virus. Both can lead to severe dehydration (due to diarrhea and less drinking) and both can lead to death if left untreated. You should contact your vet as soon as possible.

At 6 months your cat should have a full set of vaccines. If not, you know what to catch up on...

You should also research the many things that are poisonous to cats. Start with essential oils. All essential oils (with only very few exceptions) are poisonous to cats. Read more in [question 1](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/11191/12501) and [question 2](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/21166/12501). You should not use any air refresheners or cleaning products with essential oils.

Then read about common food items that are poisonous to cats (like onions, garlic and avocado) and make sure your cat cannot come in contact with any of them.

And lastly, have a look at all plants in flower pots or in your garden your cat could reach. Make sure none of them are toxic as well.